# Error when building a new solution in xamarin.forms on Mac

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

When I am creating new solution in vs for mac (xamarin.form) after building project i am getting this error.

My existing project working fine. I am getting this for new solution.

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(3,3): Error: No installed provisioning profiles match the installed iOS signing identities. (Myxamapp.iOS)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is exactly what is says in the message - you do not have a provisioning profile that matches the bundle id in your manifest.

[See here for instructions on how to set one up](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/manual-provisioning/)

It might be worth setting up a wildcard profile that will work across a number of apps while in development.